# how to redirect the user to Page 404 from URL

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I have a php script that redirect the user to a specific page based on a record id (e.g. example.com/page.php?id=4)

My question is: How can I redirect the user to the 404 Error page if he type in the browser a record id that doesn't exists? (e.g. example.com/page.php?id=59542)

Although, putting an id that doesn't exists in the DB shows no data, but the user still can see the page template.. but with empty data...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using if statements check if there is such ID in the database, if it does not exist, do:
header("Location: 404.php");
You can change 404.php to your 404 file location.

Answer (score 2):

You should send a 404 header, and maybe display a custom not found page:

```
<?php 
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); 
    include("404.php"); 
?>
```

Comment: +1, Never redirect for 404 pages, this lets the user see what url they typed that was wrong, and gives them a chance to correct it.

Comment: `header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");` is a tad safer.

Comment: @SULTAN I believe you can apply his answer in your code. You said `id=59542 does not exist`, thus, check first if the id exists in the database, if it doesn't use headers for an http code error.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page, (a complete page, with CSS, ...) and redirect to that page every 404.

Example: Look what google does https://www.google.com/adlkfjaoie43 they created a page to redirect to.